# EJB does not deploy properly in Eclipse Galileo and JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am using eclipse 3.5 with JBoss inside.
There is one project that we are currently working on.
The problem is that when I deploy the project it reports an exception:

```
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(EAR.ear)
```

with a nested exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: project1.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear
```

The problem occurs because the ear does not have the project, as described above, but it only occurs when the projects are in "synchronized" status on the server.

If I change any file in project1, it does deploy the project1.jar, but not the other projects that are still in synchronized status, and the exception is on some other dependencies between the projects.

The project1 is "EJB Project" in eclipse, the dependent projects are regular projects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are your dependent projects created as Utility projects, or are these plain Java projects which you have inherited as dependencies in your EJB?

If they are not utility projects, I would suggest creating them as Utilities, since that is the preferred and recommended way of demarcating classes that are are intended to be shared across projects.